# INNER JOIN 3 tables with reference INFILE

Tags: mysql, csv, inner-join

I have a csv with two columns, col1 is a barcode, col2 is stock quantity.

I have the 3 tables.
Table1:product_option_value
Fields: product_option_value_id, product_option_id, product_id, option_id, option_value_id, quantity, subtract, price, price_prefix, points, points_prefix, weight, weight_prefix

Table2: product_option_newvalue
Fields: product_id, product_option_value_id, sku, upc

I am trying to update the QUANTITY field of the table product_option_value using the sku and quantity in my CSV file, the part I’m having trouble with is I have to use product_option_value_id in the product_option_newvalue table to update QUANTITY field in product_option_value, how would I reference between the two?

Here is what I have. It does not work.

```
CREATE TABLE oc_product_import LIKE oc_product_option_value;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/out.csv'
       INTO TABLE oc_product_import 
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
       (sku, quantity);
UPDATE oc_product_option_value AS R 
INNER JOIN oc_product_import AS P 
       ON R.product_option_value_id = P.product_option_value_id 

SET R.quantity = P.sku; 
DROP TABLE product_import;"
```

Edit: my issue seems to be that the barcode is only stored in product_option_newvalue, and can only be linked to quantity by referencing product_option_value_id, in both tables, To update the quantity in the product_option_value table.

EDIT2: This is similar code that is working for me. But it does not have to reference PRODUCT_OPTION_VALUE_ID issue I’m working with in the two table as the barcode is included in the product table and not an additional table by reference

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oc_product_import; 
CREATE TABLE oc_product_import LIKE oc_product
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/out.csv'
INTO TABLE oc_product_import 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ';'
(sku, quantity);
UPDATE oc_product AS R 
INNER JOIN oc_product_import AS P 
ON R.sku = P.sku 
SET R.quantity = P.quantity; 
DROP TABLE oc_product_import;"
```

Comment: The WHERE was just left there while I was brain storming, I added an edit to better explain the logic I’m having trouble understanding. This is a temporary table that will be dropped after updating.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I do not yet have an error code because I have not run the SQL, as I do not understand the logic behind what I’m trying to do, I do have some code I wrote that works but it is only done with two tables, not using the reference of PRODUCT_OPTION_VALUE_ID, I’ll include the working code I have in a second edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).  It isn't the best, but it definitely makes situations like these easier to manage.

After you get it setup you can right click on a table and select `table data import wizard` and manually add a csv file that way.

If you get any errors with this let me know.

Also, if you are on mac you can simply `brew cask install mysqlworkbench` in terminal.

Comment: I’m writing a script to run server side. So using MySQL work bench to load the data will not work.